# Vulnerability: hijacking VPN-tunneled TCP connections

Tags: vpn

A new vulnerability affect all Linux disro - How can I check if my OS (elementary OS) is affected by this so called "VPN-tunneled TCP connections."
Further: How can I turn ON Reverse Path Forwarding as one of the possible mitigation solution to avoid being hihjack?

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS actual : Hera 5.1 is based on Ubutnu 18.04.

I think you talked about the vulnerability [CVE-2019-14899](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2019-14899).

after some research the vulnerability does not affect the version of Ubuntu released before version 19.10, you have more information here :

https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/94764/hacking/cve-2019-14899-vpn-flaw.html